# Ionic 3 enable swipe back for a single page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've disabled 'swipe back' globally, both in root component and module config

```
<ion-nav #appNav [root]="rootPage" swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>

...
IonicModule.forRoot(MobileApplication, {swipeBackEnabled: false}),
...
```

I need though to enable it for one page only. So'm trying to set it by passing a nav instance to constructor and then setting swipeBackEnabled to true.

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.nav.swipeBackEnabled = true;
    console.log('swipeBackEnabled ' + this.nav.swipeBackEnabled);
    console.log('canGoBack ' + this.nav.canGoBack());
    console.log('canSwipeBack ' + this.nav.canSwipeBack());
}
```

Logging swipeBackEnabled and canGoBack returns true, but canSwipeBack returns false. If I add a swipe event somewhere in my template and log those values on right swipe, it logs all the values as true. However, nothing happens, seems like swipe back is not working? Am I missing something?

For reference, I'm using Ionic 3.9.2 and @ionic/app-scripts 3.1.4. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your `this.nav`?

Comment: @duannx it's an instance of a ionic nav
`import {Nav} from "ionic-angular";`

Comment: Just change it to `navCtrl` which injected in `constructor`

Comment: @Duannx sad to say it didn't change anything. I thought Nav is just a mapping for NavController? Anyways, what's bothering me is that canSwipeBack returns false when view is loaded.

Comment: I do not think your `nav` is mapped to `NavController`. I tested in my project and it worked well. Please  reproduce your problem in https://stackblitz.com/ for easier debugging

Comment: @Duannx thanks for help, but reproducing would have been a bit complicated as our app is pretty big and I can't show the whole setup in a reasonable amount of time. Your comments made me think in a right direction though, appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what did the trick here, but the following setup made it work for me:

```
public ionViewWillEnter(): void {
    this.appNav.swipeBackEnabled = true;
}

public ionViewDidLeave(): void {
    this.appNav.swipeBackEnabled = false;
}
```

appNav here is an instance of ionic NavController. I don't yet fully understand why setting swipeBackEnabled in other lifecycle hooks didn't make it, so I'll continue investigating later on. This might be a starting point for someone who might encounter same issue though.

Comment: I like this approach, but it might be better to use `ionViewDidEnter` instead of `ionViewWillEnter`. The reason being that if you are trying to disable swipe back on a  page (rather than enable as you have done here) you can get a situation where you are trying to swipe back to a page that has this code and the swipeBack can get disabled before the swipe is finished which freezes up the app (well in my version of ionic-angular anyway).

Comment: It didn't work for me, as I understand from sources, ionic checks if swipe shall be enabled before entering the page. In this case I just saved previous page settings in my navigation service to avoid such collision

Answer (score 1):

to do this create an id for your ion-menu like i have given main-menu. to access it in your controller part.

**app.html**

```
<ion-menu [content]="appNav" id="main-menu">
....
....
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav #appNav [root]="rootPage" swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

inside your app.component.ts file place the below code inside your constructor

```
  menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false, 'main-menu');
```

so the above code acts as disabling the side menu swipe to open functionality through entire app.

lets say you want to enable the swipe to open side menu in only one page so add the below code

```
this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(true, 'main-menu');
```

this will enable the swipe to open the side menu functionality.

**Note:** Once you used the swipeEnable(true,'main-menu'); this will be able to access to the entire app. Inorder to resolve it use in only one the respeted page page and disable is to the previous page and next page respected to the current page.

> only enable it on the current page and disable it on the front and back page of that current page

**UPDATE:**

another way to achive this is enable and disable it on the same page.

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(true, 'main-menu');
}
```

and disable it on the same page by using ionviewdidleave

```
ionViewDidLeave(){
    this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false, 'main-menu');
}
```

So the above code will do the both method enabling and disabling the side-menu