# Ionic 3 SuperTabs enable swiping back

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am struggling in enabling the swipe back functionality in my app while using the SuperTabs. Neither enabling the swipe back locally at the page helps, nor globally at the AppModule. I have looked at some suggestions from the community here

> [Ionic 3 enable swipe back for a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47636697/ionic-3-enable-swipe-back-for-a-single-page)
>
> https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12927

but nothing helps.

I am testing on IOS 11 and my environment looks as following:

```
cli packages:

   @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
   Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
   ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
   Node       : v10.1.0
   npm        : 5.6.0 
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

Thanks for any help!